# Dropdown list from google spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

[This fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEyEh/) have a sample dropdown list which data is comes from hard coded json format as given below.

```
   var data = [
        {
        "department": "IT",
        "subject": [
            {
            "title": "Programmer",
            "services": [
                {
                "name": "example1"},
            {
                "name": "example2"}
                          ]

            },
        {
            "title": "Solutions Architect",
         "services": [
                {
                "name": "example3"},
            {
                "name": "example4"}
                          ]
},
        {
            "title": "Database Developer"}
        ]},
    {
        "department": "Accounting",
        "subject": [
            {
            "title": "Accountant"},
        {
            "title": "Payroll Officer"},
        {
            "title": "Accounts Clerk"},
        {
            "title": "Analyst"},
        {
            "title": "Financial Controller"}
        ]},
    {
        "department": "HR",
        "subject": [
            {
            "title": "Recruitment Consultant"},
        {
            "title": "Change Management"},
        {
            "title": "Industrial Relations"}
        ]},
    {
        "department": "Marketing",
        "subject": [
            {
            "title": "Market Researcher"},
        {
            "title": "Marketing Manager"},
        {
            "title": "Marketing Co-ordinator"}
        ]}
    ]
```

Is it possible to create the same type of dropdown with data in google spreadsheet? If so, what is the data format required in spreadsheet?

**EDIT:** Is it possible to create the same dropdown menu using data source something as

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query("http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0AozvCNI02VmpdDBKYUhRdVVhb2xGel91c2FkV1daYkE&single=true&gid=0&pub=1");
       query.send(handleQueryResponse);
       }
       function handleQueryResponse(response) {
          var data = response.getDataTable();
```

which is coming from [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AozvCNI02VmpdDBKYUhRdVVhb2xGel91c2FkV1daYkE&usp=sharing)